# Pb TRIGGER Before Insert SQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to check an insertion in a column before it's added to my table. If the insertion is null I want to assign a value based on another column of the same table.

My source table is 'article' it contains these columns: id, titre, resume, contenu.
If 'resume' is null I need to pick the first 150 characters in column 'contenu' to set the column 'resume'.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_article BEFORE INSERT
ON article FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF NEW.resume IS NULL
        THEN 
            SET NEW.resume = (SELECT LEFT (NEW.contenu, 150) FROM article WHERE NEW.id = article.id) ;
END IF ;
END |

DELIMITER ;
```

So... of course, it doesn't work. I think I understand why but like I'm very new in SQL I just can't find out how can I solve my problem. Any tips?

Comment: Why the `SELECT`? Do you need to get the `contenu` value from an other row, than the currently inserted one?

Comment: Yes I need to pick the first 150 characters from the column contenu to set my column resume if that one is NULL

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. From which **row** should `contenu` be picked from? From the currently inserted or another one?

Comment: Yes from the current row... that's why (i think) my code doesn't work... but no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access columns of the row which is inserted you don't need a `SELECT`, you can use the `new` pseudo row. Try to change the assignment:

```
...
SET NEW.resume = left(NEW.contenu, 150);
...
```